How can I pursue a career in bioinformatics with limited financial resources and a weak educational background?
I recently graduated from the Faculty of Computers and Information, Computing and Bioinformatics Program at Menoufia University in Egypt. Unfortunately, I feel that my university education was not very strong, which has left me feeling underprepared for the job market.
I am very passionate about bioinformatics and aspire to build a career in this field. However, I face several challenges:
Financial Constraints: I do not have the financial ability to pay for courses or certifications in dollars.
Job Search Struggles: I have been trying to find a job that pays well enough to support further education or training in bioinformatics, but I have not been successful so far. Additionally, I lack sufficient experience in the field.
Educational Aspirations: I aspire to obtain a master’s degree in computing and bioinformatics, but I am unsure how to proceed given my current situation.
Could anyone provide advice on how to overcome these challenges? Are there any affordable or free resources, scholarships, or programs that could help me improve my skills and increase my chances of getting a good opportunity in bioinformatics? Any guidance on how to gain relevant experience or find entry-level positions in this field would also be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help! I am eager to learn and grow in this field and would appreciate any support or advice you can offer. Your guidance could make a significant difference in my career journey.

Look into industry internships. And in the meantime learn Bash and Python.

How is it even possible? How can a bounty question be closed?

@pie A couple of months back  the bounty system was adjusted network-wide to allow regular moderation of bounty’d questions. See for example here.

@MisterMiyagi I wish I knew that the question is about to be closed before I put this bounty.

@MisterMiyagi btw why is this question is considered off-topic?

It's almost all off-topic. It starts by listing very specific factors (we don't take questions that couldn't be helpful to future readers), then moves onto a shopping question (we don't recommend resources, scholarships, or programs), and then ends with an out-of-scope question (about non-academic careers). I sympathize with the asker's plight, and wish we could help, but we are not career counselors, and there are good reasons we don't answer questions like this. See the [help] for more details.

It does seem strange that closing a bounty question doesn't result in refund of the bounty rep! Perhaps that's something to raise on the network meta...
